# How to deal with a conflicting global scope in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In order to partition data according to the company attached to the user, I have created a global scope that allows data to be partitioned in this way :

```php
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
{
    if (App::runningInConsole() || Auth::user()->can(Permission::CAN_NAVIGATE_OUTSIDE_SCOPE)) {
        return;
    }
    $builder->whereIn('compagny_id', Auth::user()->compagnies()->pluck('id'));
}
```

as well as; for many-to-many relationships :

```php
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
{
    if (App::runningInConsole() || Auth::user()->can(Permission::CAN_NAVIGATE_OUTSIDE_SCOPE) ) {
        return;
    }

    $builder->whereHas('compagnies', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereHas('users', function (Builder $nested) {
            $nested->where('users.id', Auth::id());
        });
    });

}
```

So far, no worries, everything works, there's a right to override the scope within the application : `Permission::CAN_NAVIGATE_OUTSIDE_SCOPE`

I had to apply this scope to the user model; because the logged-in user can access the list of other users, always segmented by the attached companies:

```php
// App\Models\User
public static function boot(): void
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('user', function (Builder $builder) {
        if(Auth::hasUser() && !App::runningInConsole()) {
            if(Auth::user()->can(Permission::CAN_NAVIGATE_OUTSIDE_SCOPE) || $builder->getModel()->id === Auth::id()) {
                return;
            }
            $builder->whereHas('compagnies', fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('compagnies.id', Auth::user()->compagnies()->pluck('id')));
        }
    });
}
```

Here we're waiting for `Auth::user()` exist before applying the scope, which seems to be working properly.

And now, how do you manage the global scope for the Compagny model?

I tried this approach:

```php
// App\Models\Compagny
public static function boot(): void
{

   parent::boot();
   static::addGlobalScope('compagny', function (Builder $builder) {
     if (Auth::hasUser() && !App::runningInConsole()) {
          if (Auth::user()->can(Permission::CAN_NAVIGATE_OUTSIDE_SCOPE)) {
              return;
          }
          $builder->whereHas('users', fn($q) => $q->where('users.id', Auth::id()));
      }
   });
}
```

But it seems that the scope conflicts with the User model. One seems to apply the scope to the other, making both unsearchable.

I've thought about using a local scope, but other problems may remain. That's why I want to stay in a global case, without other people working on the project having to worry about applying a local scope.

Thank you